# DateTime issue in vb.net regarding automatic scheduling

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

I have a program that checks for the date and minute part of my job object. If these match then it triggers a particular job.

```
   If jb.ScheduledStartTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy mm") =
 Now().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy mm") Then
                        'Do some work here.
                    End If
```

**Issue:**
If I schedule different jobs during the day at different time interval then they just work fine. I mean they are triggered and in the above code they enter the loop when it matches the current format.

However, it doesn't work when the date changes at 12:00.  Even though I have scheduled start time set to trigger at 9:00 AM in the morning it enters the loop exactly at 12:00 AM which is invalidating my logic leaving me confused.

Why is this happening?  Is my date and minute checking logic incorrect here?  Is there any better way of doing this?

I don't check for exact seconds here I just check for the minute part.

Comment: You aren't checking for the hour?

Comment: Ah! what an over-sight on my part.  Ridiculous and pathetic on my part.  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check the **hour part (HH)** of the dateteime, your format should be **"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"**

try this

```
 If jb.ScheduledStartTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") =
    Now().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") Then
                        'Do some work here.
 End If
```

Comment: It is the better approach to use the timespan to comapre the datetime differences or use datetime.compare method.

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking for a change in the day etc? Is your schedulestarttime getting changed correctly after it's been triggered.

BTW don't compare times as strings. It's painful and you will get hurt. Use `TimeSpan` you can then get how long things were.

```
If datetime.now > jb.ScheduledStartTime then
   'Do Some work.
end if
```

If you need smaller checks

```
dim myDateCheck as Datetime = datetime.now
myDateCheck = myDateCheck.AddSeconds(-myDateCheck.Second)
if myDateCheck > jb.ScheduledStartTime  then
    'Do Some work
end if
```